Cannot add filter for grouped columns on react ag-grid
I was trying to add filter on column "product" as show below in react ag-grid.
product category price1 price2 price3
apple   fruit1    3       4     5
apple   fruit2    6       8     5
carrot  veg1      5       6     9
carrot  veg2      58      25    60


The above data has been grouped by columns on product and category, and I am trying to add filter within ag-grid for column "product" but not able to do so. I was able to add filter to non-grouped columns like "price1", "price2", "price3".
Tried to add autoGroupColumnDef within defaultColDef and other options using ag-grid documentation but no luck.

Update: I was able to achieve this using autoGroupColumnDef along with filterValueGetter.
